How does a chemical species 'know' where the z axis is?
While studying chemical bonding, we take the z axis to be the inter nuclear axis, that is the axis along which sigma bonds form and perpendicular to which pi bonds form.
However, in the case of the d orbitals, there is the peculiar d$_{z^2}$ orbital which orients itself along the z axis only. My questions is, if I somehow isolate a single atom and if I 'see' its orbitals, where will the d$_{z^2}$ point itself towards? How will it know where its 'z' axis is?
My suspicion is that there is some sort of orbital 'resonance' going on similar to the resonance phenomena in organic chemistry where the electrons are delocalized in pi molecular orbitals. Of course, this is just a hypothesis and I wasn't able to find much about this.
Note that I don't know the mathematics of the wave equation.

Axes are something you apply to the atom. The atom doesn’t care. Solutions to Schrödinger’s equations in your basis are a complete basis so solutions in some other system are linear combinations of them.

Someone might have to correct me here, but I'm fairly sure the x/y/z axes are all arbitrary until the atom forms a compound/molecule and we can definitively assign axis directions. In a free atom the orbitals could point in any direction with the only restriction being that the x, y and z orbitals remain orthogonal to each other.

There's no need for the axes to be orthogonal, the vectors describing them only need to be non coplanar. But,  that restriction aside, given we can chose them to be what we want, and that life is far simpler if they are orthogonal, any sane human chooses them to be so.

@JonCuster But that doesn't answer the question as to where the dz^2 orbital points

@Nothing It is similar to using an address. In isolation, you will say that the $dz^2$ axis points 'there.' If you want to assign it a specific location, you say "it points along the z axis" with the implicit statement "... in an axis system where the axes are called x, y, and z, and x and y are both orthogonal to the z axis." You could say it points along the c axis if you defined the axes differently—that alone should tell you that we're using a system to make talking about it easier. It's not intrinsic.

There is some truth to this intuitive understanding of resonance between orbitals of bonding atoms. Mathematically their symmetry has to match. In that sense, the orbitals "pick out" each other.

In an atom there is total spherical symmetry so it does'n't matter where any of the the axes point. Molecules have lower symmetry and solving the Schroedinger equation is far simpler if we choose an axis along the principle symmetry axis of the molecule, we usually call this z.

It's useful to remember that these are not really states.  Quoting Wikipedia:

One should remember that these orbital 'states', as described here, are merely eigenstates of an electron in its orbit. An actual electron exists in a superposition of states, which is like a weighted average, but with complex number weights.

With that in mind, the orbitals are not actually as distinct as they look.  The orbitals are actually not the location of particles, as much as they are a way to decompose the wavefunction into spherical harmonics.  The dz orbital is in the z direction not because of the atom but because you chose an axis to be the z axis, and you decomposed the electron wavefunctions accordingly.  Were you to pick a different axis to be z, you would also find that it works.  You would merely decompose the wavefunction in a different (but consistent) way.
